# How do you preview image of an a file input that is label to hide the default file input style

Tags: jquery

The label override the default file input styling but the problem now is i can't get the value of the input file.

```
document.getElementById("imageUpload").onchange = function () {
alert("working");
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
    // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
    document.getElementById("blah").src = e.target.result;
};

// read the image file as a data URL.
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```

};

Comment: Can you show full sample? Are you talking about HTML tag `<label>`?

Comment: <label for='imageUpload'><i class='fas fa-image'></i></label>
                        <input type="file" id="imageUpload" onchange="readURL(this)" name="photo" accept="image/*" class="attachment_upload">

Comment: So you have 2 events. One is in HTML `onchange="readURL(this)"`, the other is your posted code. Maybe they try to do same job twice?